# R studio, one multi core CPU vs dual single cores

Tags: r, parallel, rstudio

So far I was using R on my home pc: i3 CPU, two cores, 4 threads. In order to run the code faster I was using the package "DoSnow", utilizing 3 out of the 4 cores in order not to choke my system completely.

However, now I got a server which has a two single core Xenons and I wonder: can I use the same multi core code for multi cpus? If no, how can I run them together and at about 70% (again, in order to not choke the system)? So far, all the codes I found on the net refer to cores rather then cpus